# How do I bind a state of a NSMenuItem (enabled) to a specific value of an NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I bind a state of a NSMenuItem (enabled) to a specific value of an NSNumber ?

i.e.

> if myNumber ==2 then my NSMenuItem should be enabled

I need to do this for several NSMenuItem:

i.e.

> if myNumber = 3 then my second NSMenuItem should be enabled

thanks

Comment: So what's the value to disable your second NSButton?

Comment: @EmptyStack probably myNumber < 3

Comment: Can I specify such statements: like myNumber == 2 in bindings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a transformer, I think you'd have to write it yourself, as in [this example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/CustomTransformer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002167-BAJEAIEE). It will register a *class* which defines a value transformer, which the system will then instantiate.

In case  you want to register an *instance* as a value transformer, [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/Registration.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002166-BAJEAIEE) has the details. The advantage if this will be that you can configure each instance differently without having to define a class for each situation.

Comment: So, since for each button the TRUE value corresponds to a different value. should I create a transformer for each button ? ie. For button1, the transformer returns YES if value is 5, NO otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IBOutlet` to your `NSButton` and disable all the button from interface builder. then use If else condition and enable your button.

```
IBOutlet NSButton *my1;// Disable  
IBOutlet NSButton *my2; //Disable   
If(myNumber ==1)
 [my1 setState:NSOnState];
else If(myNumber ==2)
 [my1 setState:NSOnState];
```

Comment: You can't do this in a binding. You need a transformer, as @Monolo indicates.

Comment: Ya exactly, that's my point. Read the comment I've just made to Monolo and I made to Ajeet Pratap Maurya before your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found `ValueTransformer`s to be too cumbersome for this. It gets much simpler than that. Just create a controller object like below

```
class FooMenuController: NSObject {

    @IBAction func selectedNumberChanged(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        UserDefaults.fooNumber = sender.tag
    }
}

extension FooMenuController: NSMenuItemValidation {

    func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
        let on = (menuItem.tag == UserDefaults.fooNumber)
        menuItem.state = on ? .on : .off
        return true
    }
}
```

In your `MainMenu.xib` drag out an `NSObject` instance from the library and set it to your `FooMenuController` subclass. Now set the `action` on every `NSMenuItem` to `FooMenuController.selectedNumberChanged` and its `tag` value to the number it should represent.

Voila.

Answer (score -1):

you can bind its(NSButton) "value" in IB

Comment: He wants a solution using [Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/).

Comment: But for each button is different: basically for each button I need a transformer, transforming a specific value (i.e. 3) to YES and all other values are NO.